# Components disappear while scroll on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, angular, components, rendering

I am developing an Angular application that consists of multiple components. While testing on Safari, everything functions correctly. However, when I test on Chrome and the number of components increases, certain components become hidden. Hovering my mouse over these components makes them visible again. This appears to be a rendering issue specifically affecting Chrome. I would greatly appreciate any advice or recommendations on how to address this matter.

Refer to the attachments.
[image]
[image]

I've already made extensive efforts to optimize all components and CSS, and even restructured the code. Unfortunately, the issue persists exclusively in Chrome. I'm seeking guidance and assistance to identify and resolve this lingering problem. Your insights would be invaluable in achieving compatibility across browsers, including Chrome. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Provide your code. If you have 100500 elements that have another 100500 child elements - then what is happening is normal.